# RESTful JBoss7 POST JSon gson

Tags: json, rest, post, gson, jboss7.x

I am using  JBoss7.1.1. I have to write a RESTful web service that receive a json file. I want to use gson library to deserialize data, is it possible in JBoss7.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

definitely yes.
But since you are using Restful web service, you could simply use RestEasy annotations(resteasy comes with Jboss 7.1.1)

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Resteasy would handle the conversion to the object type you mention in the method arguments

**TO use Gson**
you just have to add Gson library to the classpath to use it in your code

```
Gson gson=new gson();
Class reference=gson.toJson(yourJsonString,ClassName.class);
```

if you are using maven: its even more easier, just add Gson dependency in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```